# How to vertically align content within a div

Tags: html, css

I am struggling centering content vertically. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I need a float left as there will be more content on the side which you can't see but yeah how can I get this text to vertically be in the center? Also I am not sure if I do need a

tag in the  tag

```
.newsletter_text_section {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
    font-size:24px;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.newsletter_text_section p {
    font-size:24px !important;
      display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

<!-- newsletter section -->

<div class="newsletter_section">

<div class="newsletter_text_section">
<p>Join Balance and get 20% off your first order</p>
</div>

<div class="newsletter_gif_section">
...
</div>

<div class="newsletter_input_section">
...
</div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this, the faster way is to set the same pixel for `height` and `line-height` of the element. Like this:

```
.box{
  height : 10vh;
  line-height: 10vh
}
```

Otherwise, you can also `display: flex` to layout your page, in `flex` scope, you can use `align-item`  to align element vertically like this :

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

For more detailed information, you can refer to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container).

The next method is to adjust `padding` to your parent element since you are using the `percent` unit, but I don't recommend this way due to it exist side-effect sometimes.

The above content is what I think so now, hope it can help you.

Comment: Hi Watson,  if you don't mind, can you show how flexob works with my example as I explored this but couldn't get it to work?

Comment: For now I set the height and line height as that worked, thank you :)

Comment: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Halu/vr9kL4y0/5/)
I removed no need code with your example, `display: flex` needs to set for your parent element, meanwhile, I don't like to use **float** to styled my element, **float** is means float above elements, it will appear unexpected result sometimes.

Comment: Thank you Watson :) I might have to post a question showing the whole strip as it does have an affect on all other elements

Answer (score -1):

Add This To The Style Of The Element:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
```

Thanks,
Kamesta